# Exclude a directory from git diff

Tags: git

I'm wondering how I can exclude an entire directory from my Git diff.  (In this case /spec).  I'm creating a diff for our entire software release using the git diff command.  However the changes to the specs are irrelevant for this procedure, and just create headaches.  now I know i can do

```
git diff previous_release..current_release app/
```

This would create a diff for all the changes in the app directory, but not for instance, in the lib/ directory.  Does anyone know how to accomplish this task?  Thanks!

Edit:  I just want to be clear, I know I can just string the parameters of all of my directories on the end, minus /spec.  I was hoping there was a way to truly exclude a single directory in the command.

Comment: I found this amazing question because I was aiming to ignore _submodules_. In this case, if you are as naive as me, [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240881/) can be more helpful.

Comment: That's strange that we still have no native Git switch for doing this on Sep 2016

Answer (score 494, accepted):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21079437/442698) you can also use:

```
git diff previous_release..current_release -- . ':!spec'
```

This is a newish git feature which allows excluding certain paths. It should be more reliable than various shell oneliners.

I'm posting this here because this question is still the #1 hit for "git diff exclude path".

Since Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), you can replace `!` with `^`. The latter doesn't need quotes. So you can write it as:

```
git diff previous_release..current_release -- . :^spec
```

Comment: Love this answer. If adding options then do so before the double dash. Eg: 

`git diff previous_release current_release --name-status -- . ':!spec'`

Comment: Didn't realize I could use branch names for the `current_release` and `previous_release` - made me smile when I figured it out.

Comment: What worked for me `git diff --stat dev -- . ':!/Mopy/Docs/*'`. What did _not_ work for me `git diff dev --stat -- . ':!('Mopy/Docs/Wrye Bash General Readme.html'|'Mopy/Docs/Wrye Bash Advanced Readme.html')'` and variations

Comment: Really helpful. Here is the syntax to see if any files are changed, other than database.yml: `git diff --check -- . ':!config/database.yml'`

Comment: Can also exclude multiple items like so: `git diff previous_release current_release -- . ':!file_a' ':!file_b'`

Comment: For ```git diff -- . ':!_site'``` it gives ```fatal: Unimplemented pathspec magic '_' in ':!_site'```

Comment: This works for me without needing any `.` after the `--`.  Just `git diff [..arguments...] -- ':!thing-to-exclude'`

Comment: The manpage this is documented in is `gitglossary`.

Comment: This follows the normal rules for filespecs in git, so if you specify an entire directory, git includes all folders and subfolders under it. So `:^/Path/To/*` can be the simpler `:^/Path/To`. There's also no need to add the `.` because git assumes you intend all files as the starting point if the only pathspecs are exclusions. Do `git help glossary` to see all the docs for these. Last, this command is sensitive to the current directory. If you are at the root, don't need the initial `/`.

Comment: Note this doesn’t work with `--no-index`.

Comment: the "latter version" describes using the carrot as needing no quotes (`:^spec`); keep in mind carrot notation will still need quotes on zsh if you use wildcards, e.g. `":^*.lock"` --for what it's worth :) (I liked the notion of a more succinct command, but the exceptions rob just a little of the joy)

Answer (score 150):

Assuming you use bash, and you've enabled extended globbing (`shopt -s extglob`), you could handle that from the shell side:

```
git diff previous_release current_release !(spec)
```

Saves you having to list all other things.

Or, shell-agnostic:

```
git diff previous_release current_release --name-only | grep -v '^spec/' \
    | xargs git diff previous_release current_release --
```

You could wrap that up in a one-liner shell script to save yourself having to retype the arguments.

Comment: P.S. globbing doesn't match hidden files, so if you're obsessive, you might want to tack on `.!(.|)` to match everything starting with a `.` besides `.` and `..`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for files that are brand new or deleted across branches. I get errors that halt execution of the script, saying it can't diff against it.

Comment: @Graham: I believe that the `--` I just added should fix that.

Comment: Awesome answer. I only wanted names to show (not the actual diff) so I had to add `--name-only` at the very end as well.

Comment: After playing around with it, just wanna add that if you change the name of a file, it will throw an error but all you need to do is add `-- path/of/new/file` and it will figure it out :)

Comment: @Jefromi, Thanks man this work for me, but, How can I exclude more than one folder? !(spec,spec2) or !(spec) ,!(spec2) ?

Comment: @AbyW, [using the pipe](https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/bash-extended-globbing) `|`, like `!(spec*|foo|bar)`.

Answer (score 50):

If you want to specify more than one path to exclude in a git diff, you just add additional exclusion parameters to the end, e.g. to exclude everything in *vendor* and *bin* directories from the stats:-

```
git diff --stat previous_release..current_release -- . ':!vendor' ':!bin'
```

Answer (score 38):

You can try and unset the diff attribute for any files within the lib directory.
[`.gitattributes`](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes):

```
lib/* -diff
```

---

[racl101](https://stackoverflow.com/users/295019/racl101) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380945/exclude-a-directory-from-git-diff/4381039#comment87575283_4381039):

> Just to add to this, for those of you who want to limit the `git diff` output of files of a specific type, within a specific directory and its subdirectories, like all the JavaScript generated by Webpack's bundling of your `.js` files, for example, you can add this to `.gitattributes`:

```
dist/js/**/*.js -diff
```

> Then you don't see all that noise in your git diff output and it just shows as: `Binary files ... differ` which is more helpful.

Comment: this would remove spec from all of my diffs though.  I still want to see my diffs in the spec folder normally, just not when i'm running this 'release' diff

Comment: @Mystr: You could set that `.gitattributes` file in a special branch made only for this kind of 'release' diff ;) Rebase that special branch on top of `current_release` and do your diff from there.

Comment: This, too doesn't seem to work for files that are deleted across branches. Files which were removed still show the complete diff.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Are _ paths special?
```_site/* -diff```

Comment: @MariusAndreiana No, '_' is not special. Can you check which gitattributes rule apply for a file of that folder with: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-attr

Comment: ```git-check-attr -a _site/index.html``` gives ```_site/index.html: diff: unset```. It actually works, I was confused by the output ```Binary files a/_site/index.html and b/_site/index.html differ``` -- I see that's expected. Thanks!

Answer (score 35):

### Relative to the git root directory

`git diff` accepts an optional exclude

```
git diff -- ":(exclude)thingToExclude"
```

### You might want to add some wild cards

```
git diff -- ":(exclude)*/thingToExclude/*"
```

### Target specific file types

```
git diff -- ":(exclude)*/$1/*.png"
```

### Some syntactical sugar applied

```
git diff -- ":!/\$1/"
```

#### Or drop a little script for your dotfiles

#### Such as `.bash_profile` or `.zshrc`

```
gde() {
    : '
        git diff exclude files or folders
        usage:
        gde fileOrFolderNameToExclude
    '
    git diff -- ":!/\$1/"
}
```

Answer (score 29):

Git diff now accepts a custom exclusion format: `git diff -- ':(exclude)lib/*'`

Be careful if you have a lot of repetitive folder names ('/app', '/lib', etc.), as this will exclude files relative to the current working directory AND the git root directory.

Comment: are you missing a dot, shouldn't it rather be `git diff -- . ':(exclude)lib/*'`?

Comment: @NicolasDermine No, though what you wrote is equivalent. The "includes" portion of the path is also optional. That's why you can just do `git diff` for everything relative to your current path, rather than requiring `git diff -- .`

Comment: Note: on windows machines, use double quotes, like `git diff -- ":(exclude)lib/*"`

Comment: No idea why, but for me it works only with the dot, as suggested by @NicolasDermine . I use Cmder on win10.

Comment: When the folder to exclude was not a direct subfolder of the root folder of the diff I had to precede it with */ also.  Ex. `git diff -- . ":!*/lib/*"`    Using `!` is shorthand for `(exclude)`

Answer (score -8):

```
git diff app lib
```