# git diff branch --name-status --ignore

Tags: git

Is there a way to ignore a path(s) when doing git diff?

such as git diff branch --name-status --ignore=this/path

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack but you could do this.

```
git diff banch --name-status | grep -v this/path
```

Not entirely git, but does the job.

Answer (score 1):

As they ~say here: [Exclude a directory from git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380945/exclude-a-directory-from-git-diff), you can use something like this:

```
git diff --name-only $branch_name | grep -v -E "$excluding" | xargs git diff $branch_name --
```

...where `branch_name` is the other branch and `excluding` is the pattern you'd like to exclude. I'm not sure if git-diff will eventually provide a parameter for something like that, and I didn't find such an option in the git documentation, so this command is what I use for now.

The only caveat is that *you have to be at the top level of your working directory* (i.e., the same folder that contains your .git folder) for this command to work, since the paths you pass in to `git diff --` at the end via `xargs` are relative to that.

You can make a script out of this to do the work for you in your favorite shell, e.g.

```
#!/bin/zsh

if [[ $# < 2 ]] ; then
    echo "Usage: \n   gdx [git-diff-params] branch_name extended_reg_exp\n"
    echo "\nExamples:\n   gdx development jpg \n   gdx --name-only master origin/master jar \n   gdx development '[a-zA-Z]+'"
    exit 1
fi

excluding="$@[-1]"
branch_name="$@[-2]"
diff_options="$@[1,-3]"

## Get a list of all the paths to include
git_paths=$(git diff --name-only $branch_name | grep -v -E "$excluding")

if [[ ${#git_paths} = 0 ]] ; then
    #no diffs
    exit 0
else
    ## Escape special characters
    git_paths=(${(f)git_paths})
    for i in {1..${#git_paths}}
    do
        git_path=$git_paths[i]
        git_path=\"${git_path//\"/\"}\"
        git_paths[i]=$git_path
    done

    ## Run the diff
    eval "git diff ${=diff_options} $branch_name -- $git_paths"
fi
```

This takes arguments and prints usage and whatnot. I use it like so:

```
gdx HEAD^ "*.jar"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the paths you don't care about to your .gitignore file.

EDIT: You can use `git diff files/you/care/about` to see the diffs you are interested in.

For example, if `git status` shows that a bunch of files are changed:

```
modified: foo/bar
modified: foo/baz
modified: some/more/stuff
modified: and/some/more
```

you can use `git diff foo` to just look at the changes in the `foo` directory, or `git diff some/more/stuff and/some/more` to look at everything except `foo`.

This will be fine if you want to look at the diffs for a few files, but won't work so well if you want to look at everything *except* one or two files. I don't think there's a way to tell `git diff` to use a negation of the files you specify.

Another alternative would be to use `git add --interactive`, but it's probably a bit cumbersome for what you're doing.

It also turns out that `.gitignore` doesn't ignore files that are already under version control, so that idea was never going to work. Forget I mentioned it. :(

Comment: I am just trying to ignore certain files that might be different with the diff command.