# Run pipeline only on changes in one dir

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

So I've got a project with some structure. And whenever I push changes to any file pipeline is run. But I want it to run only when there are changes in particular directory. Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may help you:

[Determine If Any File Changed In Directory For Latest Git Commit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067130/determine-if-any-file-changed-in-directory-for-latest-git-commit)

that way if there are no changes in your directory you could finish the build early.

Answer (score 23):

The [JIRA issue](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-16560) that refers to this situation was recently updated with the [following solution](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/BCLOUD-16560?focusedCommentId=2379573&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-2379573) that can be straightforward applied.

Example from bitbucket blog post:

```
- step:
          name: build-frontend-artifact
          condition:
              changesets:
                  includePaths:
                    # only xml files directly under resources directory
                    - "src/main/resources/*.xml"
                    # any changes in frontend directory
                    - "src/site/**"
          script:
             - echo "Building frontend artifact"
```

Answer (score -1):

Check this Documentation

https://bitbucket.org/blog/conditional-steps-and-improvements-to-logs-in-bitbucket-pipelines

```
- step:
      name: build-frontend-artifact
      condition:
          changesets:
              includePaths:
                # only xml files directly under resources directory
                - "src/main/resources/*.xml"
                # any changes in frontend directory
                - "src/site/**"
      script:
         - echo "Building frontend artifact"
```