# Bitbucket server: Send email when pushing a commit that modifies files inside a specific folder

Tags: git, bitbucket-server

Is there any way to send an email when someone pushes one or more commits that modifies files inside a folder?

I have a folder with files that contain generic code that shouldn't be changed in most of the commits. But if someone pushes a change on those files, I would like to trigger an email/slack notification.

Is it possible to do with BitBucket server? maybe is there a plugin that allows me to do that?

Comment: I am fairly certain that Jenkins can handle this requirement.

Comment: I'll check that out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are talking about bitbucket.org, meaning a Git repository hosting server you don't have a direct access/control to, you need to [setup a webhook](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/manage-webhooks-735643732.html)

That webhook will call the web listener of your choice, which can inspect the [push JSON payload](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/event-payloads-740262817.html#EventPayloads-Push), and fetch the new commits into a local repo.

From there, you can make a diff, and check if a [specific directory content has changed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067330/6309).

And yes, as commented, a Jenkins server (that you control) can be used as a webhook listener, with the [JENKINS/Generic Webhook Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Generic+Webhook+Trigger+Plugin).

The [OP Gaston K](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5258073/gaston-k) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54008049/bitbucket-server-send-email-when-pushing-a-commit-that-modifies-files-inside-a/54010761?noredirect=1#comment94871529_54010761):

> I'm using bitbucket server, which is basically the same but running on my end, I guess.

Then, if you have access to the server, you can setup a post-receive hook: see "[Atlassian / BitBucket / Using repository hooks](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver/using-repository-hooks-776639836.html)".
You will use the [Repository Hook Plugin Module](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/reference/plugin-module-types/repository-hook-plugin-module/?_ga=2.205431440.1484800156.1546450269-860143003.1542618875), to define a [hook of type "`PostRepositoryHook`"](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/bitbucket/how-tos/hooks-merge-checks-guide/)

You can then, using the [Atlassian SDK](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/set-up-the-atlassian-plugin-sdk-and-build-a-project/), code a class which implements that type:

```
public class NotificationPostRepositoryHook implements PostRepositoryHook<RepositoryHookRequest> {
```

(see for instance [Creating a New Plugin from Scratch](https://developer.atlassian.com/server/framework/atlassian-sdk/frequently-used-commands/) to get started)

Comment: I'm using bitbucket server, which is basically the same but running on my end, I guess. What do you suggest in that case? Setting up a webhook as well?

Comment: @GastonK I have edited the answer to address your comment.