# Post-receive githook for loop

Tags: python, git-post-receive

Is there logic that can check if the push included the creation of a new file in the a files directory in git repo?

I am looking to execute a python script only if the push had a new file created in the files directory.

One example [uses git diff --name-only --diff-filter=A and grep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45067130/determine-if-any-file-changed-in-directory-for-latest-git-commit)

Which does look to answer my question, how could I use a for loop to execute the python script x amount of times using each new file set as a parameter?

Eg. 3 new files added to the directory githook to then execute the python script 3 times each time passing the new file as a variable?