# How to know if I have latest version of file [git lfs lock workflow]

Tags: git, git-lfs

We are using `git lfs lock` ([GitHub's open source git extension](https://git-lfs.github.com)) to prevent conflicts with binary files. The problem is that sometimes people forget to pull the latest version of a file, they lock the file and work on it but get rejected when trying to push.

*So how can I quickly check if I have the latest version of the file*, before locking it?

Comment: Note that there's no `git lock` included with Git itself; this must be some add-on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can:

- fetch first
- check if there is [a diff for that specific file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57290902/6309), compared to origin/master (assuming you are on master)

That is:

```sh
git fetch
if git diff --quiet origin/master -- yourFile; then
   echo "No changes"
else 
   echo "File changed, let's reject log"
fi
```