# Bash Script - Determine whether to add file to Git commit

Tags: bash, git

This is probably a simple one for a bash scripter, which I am not.

I'm running a cron job that downloads some data, and then depending on that data, may or may not modify a second file. After the job, I want to `git commit` one or both files.  For the conditional commit, I tried this in a .sh script:

```
# attempt to capture whether MyNotes.txt was changed
# by counting lines in git status output
mywc=(git status -s MyNotes.txt | wc -l)
echo $mywc found!
if [ $mywc = 1 ]; then
   echo Add file for commit
else
   echo Nothing to add
fi
```

I'm pretty much getting nowhere; this thing seems to fail on the first line with ***syntax error near unexpected token '|'***. If I run `git status -s MyNotes.txt | wc -l` on the command line, I get the numeric output I expect.

1. What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?
2. If there's a more elegant way to determine whether a file changed, feel free to share.

Also, for my edification, how could I get this to work without the interim `mywc` variable? I.e., if I wanted to just do the command within the `if`, something like this:

```
if [[ $(git status -s MyNotes.txt | wc -l) = 1 ]]; then
...
```

Thanks!

Comment: `mywc=$(git status -s MyNotes.txt | wc -l)` (put $ before open paren) ?

Comment: Ugh... I literally just tried that before I saw your comment, and yes, that seems to work. I've been banging my head against the wall on this, and figured it was something dumb I was doing. Thank you, @CryptoFool. But I think my `IF` statement is still failing. I'm looking into that now.

Comment: Note that your script so far does not actually commit anything. In general the phrase "commit a file" might not be what you mean; every commit contains _all_ your files.

Comment: @matt, I updated the question title to what I think is more correct verbiage.

Comment: Since `git add .` would embrace this file if it has indeed changed, why not just say that? What's the need for the conditional?

Comment: You're right. No need for conditional after all.

Comment: Since the (correct) answer did not explain, **why** you got a syntax error: If you write `a=(foo bar baz)`, you are  storing into `a` a 3-element array with these values. The symbol `|` denotes a pipe for bash, and a pipe does not make sense inside an array denotation. Hence the syntax error. To store a pipe symbol into an array (in case you need this one day), you would have to quote it: `a=(foo bar '|' baz)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

put a dollar before parenthesis.

```
foo=$(command)
```

The thing you are using looks like a bash array

```
declare -a letters=(a b c d)
```

> If there's a more elegant way to determine whether a file changed, feel free to share.

Consider this:

```
$ git diff -s --exit-code README.md || echo has changed
has changed
$ git checkout  README.md
Updated 1 path from the index
$ git diff -s --exit-code README.md || echo has changed
```

The OR (||) runs if the first command exits with a non-zero code.
Same thing essentially:

```
$ false || echo false exits with 1 
false exits with 1
$ true  || echo will not trigger
```

An aspect of bash that people overlook is that [[, ]], [ and  ] are separate commands. They have return codes too. With this knowledge, you can leverage the return codes with if and any other command.

```
$ if true; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
$ if false; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

So for detecting changes in a tracked file:

```
$ if git diff -s --exit-code README.md; then echo same as in index; else echo changed; fi 
same as in index

$ echo 123 >> README.md 
$ if git diff -s --exit-code README.md; then echo same as in index; else echo changed; fi 
changed
```

---

With all of that said...

Just add the file. You don't need to check anything. If it hasn't changed, nothing will happen.

```
$ echo foo >> myfile
$ git add myfile
$ git commit -m 'maybe changed' myfile
[master b561cc1] maybe changed
1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)

$ git add myfile
$ git commit -m 'maybe changed' myfile
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

if you need to avoid a non-zero exit code (such as with set -e), just put a `|| true` after the command that you want to ignore the exit status of:

```
$ cat foo.sh

  #!/bin/basho
  
  set -e
  
  echo foo >> myfile
  git add myfile
  git commit -m 'maybe changed' myfile
  
  git add myfile
  git commit -m 'maybe changed' myfile > /dev/null || true
  
  echo no error here. it\'s fine..
  
  false
  
  echo fill never reach this.
```

Try running that script and see what happens

Answer (score 1):

I search for [a way for checking if file changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17797740/check-if-specific-file-in-git-repository-has-changed).

```
git diff --exit-code -s <path>
```

Now the bash scripter knows that every command returns a status code which can be checked with `$?`. In case everything went smoothly, 0 is returned. In that case we get 0 if file is **not** changed.

Every bash scripter knows too that you can use that with `&&` and `||` operators (because of lazy evaluation) to write such construct:

```
git diff --exit-code -s <path> && echo "should add file"
```

About your edification, what you wrote is perfectly fine!

Comment: Clever. But I don't think this will work with untracked files in git.

Answer (score 1):

As CryptoFool pointed out in a comment, I failed to include a `$` in my variable assignment.  Simple fix in the first line of my script:

```
mywc=$(git status -s MyNotes.txt | wc -l)
```

As matt pointed out in a subsequent comment, doing a `git add` on a file that hasn't changed has no effect. It won't stage the file for commit.  So instead of doing conditional logic to determine *whether* to `git add myfile.txt`, I'll just blindly execute `git add myfile.txt`, which will either stage the file if there are changes, or do nothing if there are no changes.  Therefore, my entire script can be replaced with one line:

```
git add MyNotes.txt
```