# Exclude a directory or file from git commit --verbose

Tags: git, bash, diff, commit, verbose

I know it is possible to ignore a directory or file from `git diff` using `git diff !(example)`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4381121/1166929).

Is this possible when using `git commit -v`?

Comment: I am not entirely sure I follow. Unless you use `-a`, `git commit` will apply to files in the index (added via `git add`).  What part of `git commit -v`don't you want? Can you give an example of files & expected output?

Comment: I want to not see the verbose comments for any files I have in my build folder, because they're not meaningful to me when I am writing the commit message.

Answer (score 1):

As long as they are on the index they will appear on the commit -v message.

You can either add them to .gitignore (but I don't think that is what you want), or manually remove the unwanted comments for each commit.