# git diff ignore everything under a directory (node_modules)

Tags: git, directory, ignore, git-diff

i have a repo where the files inside node_modules are also committed to the repo. i need to perform a git diff on the repo but want to ignore everything under node_modules. how can i do this?

i tried this `git diff old_api..master -- . ':!node_modules'` (as suggested in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374503) but it still diffs the content inside node_modules directory, e.g.:

`diff --git a/db/node_modules/bhttp/README.md b/db/node_modules/bhttp/README.md`

also i'm not sure what the `..` does so i removed it and tried this: `git diff old_api master -- . ':!node_modules'` but no difference.

any help?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to git but in the past I have cleared the cache on git and then added a .gitignore with the node module pathway included.

Here is a sample cache command:

```
git rm -r --cached .
git add .
git commit -am 'git cache cleared'
git push
```

Here is some documentation to get you started: [git ignore docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

There are also many templates around git hubs to get you started with a boilerplate .gitignore [here is a link to many excellent gitignore files](https://github.com/github/gitignore)

Comment: That's okay if you clear the cache and create a properly written .gitignore file things will sort out. By that I mean they will become removed from the repository

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `git diff -- . ':!{path to your node_modules}/node_modules'` ?

e.g.: `git diff -- . ':!myfolder/anotherfolder/node_modules'`