# Git difftool with beyond compare

Tags: git, beyondcompare, git-difftool

I am trying to compare two git branches.
With git I would do

```
git diff banch1..branch2
```

With the Beyond Compare tool I tried

```
git difftool branch1..branch2
```

but now it looks like it's comparing the branches file by file. So I added the `--dir-diff (-d)` flag

```
git difftool -d branch1..branch2
```

but now I get an error

```
fatal: could not open '/var/folders/zj/btt2_b5d6_b34fndcvzws9jr0000gn/T//git-difftool.VtceWd/left/ED/Template/sun-lncc/Template/dbged' for writing: No such file or directory
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
git diff branch1 branch2 --name-only
```

This will give you a list of files that are different between the branches. By the way, you don't have to use "branch1..branch2". Difftool visually compares files; if you specify a file:

```
git difftool branch1 branch2 -- filename
```

it will only compare those, if not, it will attempt to compare everything that's different and show you in the comparer.

As for your error, there just seems to be a file missing. Make sure you're typing everything in correctly.

Comment: Yes I actually figured out that the reason was that a folder was missing. I find this strange though. If a certain file/folder has been deleted from a certain version, why not include it in the comparison tree. I mean that could be a relevant change that I want to keep track of....

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing the problem file/directory from the diff command as specified in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29374503/275524).

e.g.

```sh
git difftool branch1 branch2 -- . :^ED/Template/sun-lncc/Template/dbged
```