# Compare folders with git diff / diff and exclusive a certain subdirectory

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I have the following folder structure:

```
| folder1 
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── subFolder1
│   │  ├── subFile1
│   │  ├── subFile2


| folder2
│   ├── file1
│   ├── file2
│   ├── subFolder1
│   │  ├── subFile1
│   │  ├── subFile2
```

I would like to check the differences between folder1 and folder2 in my desktop but excluding the subFolder1 (which have different files, but I have no interest in their differences)

Is it possible to do this with git diff or diff/ any other utility from linux?

Straight up comparison is possible with:

```
git diff folder1/ folder2/
```

However, I do not know how to exclude a folder from comparison.

I tried the commands in [Exclude a directory from git diff](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4380945/exclude-a-directory-from-git-diff) but to no success so far. I have an an error saying:

```
Not a git repository
To compare two paths outside a working tree:
usage: git diff [--no-index] <path> <path>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdiff%5D+exclude+directory

Comment: You cannot use git-specific exclusion outside of a single repository.

Comment: `diff -r -x subFolder1 folder1 folder2`

Comment: diff -r -x subFolder1 folder1 folder2| colordiff | less -R       did the trick

Comment: any idea on how to exclude multiple subFolders?

Comment: Multiple `-x`. I often use `diff -ru --speed-large-files -x CVS -x .git -x .hg -x .svn -x '*.py[co]' -x __pycache__`