# Why does "git add" not work with submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a root folder with a `git/` folder and one submodule (`mymodule`). `mymodule` has its own `git/` folder, too.

`git status` shows:

```
# modified mymodule (untracked content)
```

Then I have removed a git folder from the submodule, and now if I change something in `mymodule`, it doesn't show with `git status`.

`git add mymodule` doesn't work.

All `mymodule` changes are untracked.

Comment: What you do mean "*I have removed git folder from submodule*"? You deleted mymodule/.git folder?

Comment: Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126765/how-to-get-rid-of-git-submodules-untracked-status). May be you'll find answer there.

Comment: Alexander, rm -rf mymodule/.git

Answer (score 4):

Submodules are different repos, so when you do a `git add` it doesn't track the changes in the submodules. The root repo only contains a reference to the submodule (`mymodule`). To commit all the changes you should `cd` into `mymodule`, commit the changes and push, then go into your root project and commit. This way the commit hash you have from `mymodule` will be included in the commit for your root project.