# Tell git to ignore untracked content in submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore

Currently if I run `git status`, I get a bunch of stuff like this:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)

        modified:   projects/submodule1 (untracked content)
        modified:   projects/submod2 (untracked content)
        modified:   projects/submodule3 (new commits, modified content, untracked content)
        modified:   projects/submodule4 (modified content, untracked content)
        ...
```

I *do* care about the `new commits` and the `modified content`, but a lot of these submodule generate their own crap (like build files, etc), and I don't care about any of that (if it's important, I should be adding it to the submodule and tracking it). Is there a way to get git to ignore `untracked content` in submodules, but not `new commits` or `modified content`?

Comment: There's an exact same question with answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126765/how-to-get-rid-of-git-submodules-untracked-status

Comment: Thanks @MudassirRazvi, I've voted to close this as a duplicate.

Comment: Since there are no answers yet, you could just delete this question.