# Git Bad Object desktop.ini

Tags: github, git-pull

I used to have GoogleDrive on my PC that uploaded all my code on the drive. I was working on the main branch because I got this project on GitHub, so I deleted all the desktop.ini files and tried to pull the project to update the changes made by my co-workers, but got this error.

The problem didn't occur to me at first because GoogleDrive takes a few minutes to make all the desktop.ini, but when it did it caused problems.

```
> git pull pmo main
remote: Enumerating objects: 85, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (77/77), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (33/33), done.
remote: Total 59 (delta 25), reused 59 (delta 25), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (59/59), 6.63 KiB | 218.00 KiB/s, done.
fatal: bad object refs/desktop.ini
error: https://github.com/*******/*******.git did not send all necessary objects
```

I tried to remove the .git/refs/desktop.ini with the command `rm` but it says that i do not have access to it, even in the powershell.

Answer (score 2):

If a google drive folder (and its subfolders) are shared to other users, a `desktop.ini` file is created for the current folder and all of its subfolders. Thus, if this shared folder contains a git repo, then the `.git` folder and all of subfolders (for example, `refs`, `objects` where Git stores its own data) will contain a `desktop.ini`. Git expects all files under `.git` to contain only Git data, so it fails to understand the file content of `desktop.ini`. Looks like deleting all `desktop.ini` is not a good solution as `desktop.ini` several minute later.

For me, stop sharing the folder works. It automatically removes `desktop.ini` and won't be regenerated.

Answer (score 0):

That is why it is preferable to *not* work in a network-synchronized drive: git pull/push/clone won't work well with the concurrent synchronization that comes with a Google Drive.

It is better to save on that drive [a `git bundle`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5578292/6309) (which stores your repository in *one* file), while collaborating with others through the remote GitHub repository (cloned locally in a normal folder)

---

[Ez0r](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2798506/ez0r) suggests in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74754620/git-bad-object-desktop-ini/74757438?noredirect=1#comment135262511_74757438) to use a tool like [Everything](https://www.voidtools.com/) to search and delete any occurrences of `desktop.ini`.

Comment: Well that would solve the problems if i actually wanted to keep Drive Going, but still i am not able to use the pull.

Comment: @Pinguiz You mean:  "still i am not able to use the pull": outside any Drive folder?

Comment: yes i decided to uninstall Drive and delete all the desktop.ini files, still that problem persists.

Comment: search for desktop.ini in that git, then delete all (a tool like "everything" can help)

Comment: @Ez0r, thank you!!! Used Everything to search for desktop.ini and deleted them all. Solved a very annoying issue I've had for ages.

Comment: @Ez0r Thank you indeed. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 0):

You can also add a new file named .gitignore; in the file, add *.ini and git will ignore those files. You can find more at [How to get rid of Git submodules untracked status?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126765/how-to-get-rid-of-git-submodules-untracked-status) Github has samples at https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but this is not relevant: the problem files are in the `.git` folder and effectively corrupt the Git database, they're not untracked files in the sandbox.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35451971)

Comment: @ray Please pay attention when reviewing. This answer is **not** link-only. The links only serve for further reading, the answer it gives is _"You can also add a new file named .gitignore; in the file, add *.ini and git will ignore those files."_, which is valid and understandable even without the links. (The fact it may not be the correct answer to the question might make it downvote-worthy, but not delete-worthy.)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I understand your point. What I was thinking during the review was that the answer should include a sample of `.gitignore` file content customized to the question's context(instead of just leaving it in links) and explain how it can solve OP's problem. I am not a subject expert in this matter but I agree with you that the answer might not show obvious relevancy to the question. I 
 think the answerer could be given another chance to explain it. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: @ray See also [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer). It may be a poor answer, and could do with more details, but it is an answer, as such your review action should to select "looks OK" (and maybe downvote).

Answer (score 0):

Deleting all desktop.ini files worked for me, but it could not be made manually (there are lots of them).

I used the following code (taken from SharifMrCreed on https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/issues/611):

```
folder_path = <introduce_your_folder_path>

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(folder_path):
    for filename in files:
        if filename.lower() == "desktop.ini":
            file_path = os.path.join(root, filename)
            try:
                os.remove(file_path)
                print(f"Deleted {file_path}")
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error deleting {file_path}: {e}")
```

I hope this helps :)