# Getting rid of untracked uncommitted changes in submodules

Tags: git

How do I get rid of those untracked changes? They refer to 4 different git repositories. I've tried to remove them, clean etc. but it keeps returning this:

```
➜  theresa-sporn git:(main) git add .
➜  theresa-sporn git:(main) git commit -m "xy"
On branch main
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   TheresaPackage (modified content)
        modified:   data-challenges (modified content, untracked content)
        modified:   dotfiles (modified content, untracked content)
        modified:   practice (modified content, untracked content)

no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

Comment: See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5126905) in particular.

Comment: (note: I "accidentally" was able to single-handedly close the question as duplicate because it was incorrectly tagged with `python`)