# git add -p --ignore-submodules?

Tags: git, addition, git-submodules

**Is there a way to ignore dirty submodules when using `git add --patch`?**

I've set [`ignore = dirty` as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3240881/git-can-i-suppress-listing-of-modified-content-dirty-submodule-entries-in-stat#answer-6935474). This seems to only work with `git status` and `git diff`. I love `git add -p`. Having to skip through 10 dirty submodules every time I want to add a small change frustrates me.

I haven't quite figured out `git add -i` yet, but it looks like it handles dirty submodules the same way.

Comment: With Git 2.16.x/2.17 (Q1 2018), you won't have any more issue with submodule when doing a `git add -p` or `git add -i`: See [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48590834/6309)

Answer (score 1):

Having add silently ignore submodule updates seems, to quote Clint, tooooo dangerous.

I don't know how to do it with add --patch, but I can get pretty close with add --edit and a vim keymapping:

```
map <Leader>\x :%!sed '/^diff --git/\!{H;$\!d};x;1{$\!d;x};/\nindex[^\n]*160000\n/d'<CR>
```

while will map `\\x` to eliminate all submodule update hunks.  The `\!`s in that are vim-specific bang escapes, strip those backslashes to use the sed elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

With Git 2.16.x/2.17, you won't even need a `--ignore-submodules` option,
since  **"`git add -p`" was taught to ignore local changes to submodules** as
they do not interfere with the partial addition of regular changes
anyway.

See [commit 12434ef](https://github.com/git/git/commit/12434efc1d4a83d768e8b60bfdb711780677a308) (13 Jan 2018) by [Nguyễn Thái Ngọc Duy (`pclouds`)](https://github.com/pclouds).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e7e8077](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e7e80778e705ea3f9332c634781d6d0f8c6eab64), 23 Jan 2018)</sup>

> ### add--interactive: ignore submodule changes except HEAD
>
> For '`add -i`' and '`add -p`', the only action we can take on a dirty
>   submodule entry is update the index with a new value from its `HEAD`.
>   The content changes inside (from its own index, untracked files...) do not
>   matter, at least until '`git add -i`' learns about launching a new
>   interactive add session inside a submodule.
>
> **Ignore all other submodules changes except HEAD**.
>   This reduces the number of entries the user has to check through in '`git add -i`', and the number of '`no`' they have to answer to '`git add -p`' when dirty submodules are present.