# Do you ignore a git submodule in your .gitignore or commit it to your repo?

Tags: git

I've added a submodule to my project in `project_dir/vendor/submodule_one` now each time I run `git status` I get `modified: vendor/submodule_one (new commits)`.

My question is whats the best way to deal with this? Do I add the `vendor/submodule_one`-folder to my `.gitignore` as my main project shouldn't need to know about the specifics of my submodule?

Or when I'm changing and commiting changes to my submodule do I need to make commits in my main project also?

Just getting started with submodules and couldn't seem to find much info beyond setting them up.

Comment: Hi did you find the answer for same?I am in similar situation.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

No, you don't need to add your submodule to your `.gitignore`: what the parent will see from your submodule is a **gitlink** (a [special entry, `mode 160000`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16581096/6309)).

That means: any change directly made in a submodule needs to be followed by a commit in the parent directory.
That way, the parent directory will record the right commit for the state of the submodule: That commit is the "gitlink" mentioned above;

You can read more about that policy in "[git submodule update (true nature of submodules)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)".
The main idea behind submodules is a [component-based approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/933723/what-is-component-driven-development/933735#933735), where you reference other repos at specific commits. But if you change anything in those submodules, you need to update those references in the parent repo as well.

---

Note that with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), while *not* ignoring the gitlink, you can still ignore the submodule with:

```
git config submodule.<name>.active false
```

See more at "[Ignore new commits for git submodule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43440263/6309)".

---

Note: with Git 2.15.x/2.16 (Q1 2018), ignoring a submodule is more precise.
"`git status --ignored --untracked`" did not stop at a working tree of a separate project that is embedded in an ignored directory and listed files in that other project, instead of just showing the directory itself as ignored.

See [commit fadb482](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fadb4820c4a0178ce76c24d7b48b7ea70210727a) (25 Oct 2017) by [Johannes Schindelin (`dscho`)](https://github.com/dscho).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit da7996a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/da7996aaf75fcd58c0fb787c15ee9569140a2f9c), 06 Nov 2017)</sup>

> ### `status`: do not get confused by submodules in excluded directories
>
> We meticulously pass the `exclude` flag to the `treat_directory()` function so that we can indicate that files in it are excluded rather than untracked when recursing.
>
> But we did not yet treat submodules the same way.
>
> Because of that, `git status --ignored --untracked` with a submodule
>   `submodule` in a gitignored `tracked/` would show the submodule in the
>   "**`Untracked files`**" section, e.g.

```
On branch master
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    tracked/submodule/

Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    tracked/submodule/initial.t
```

> Instead, we would want it to show the submodule in the "**`Ignored files`**"
>   section:

```
On branch master
Ignored files:
  (use "git add -f <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    tracked/submodule/
```

Comment: This answer is confusing because the Question title is asking whether to ignore submodule folders or not, and you're answering with yes to a separate question later in the body of the question.

Comment: I think it makes much more sense now, and is providing some very useful in-depth information. Awesome, thanks for updating :)

Comment: Argument for .gitignore:  Why check-in .gitsubmodules file when the url contained therein could possibly contain a user specific git url with a username param?

Comment: @djangofan the question (and my answer) was about ignoring the submodule *folder* itself (the one representing by a gitlink). Not about ignoring the `.gitmodules` file. It is true that this one file (the `.gitmodules`) might include credentials, but if used just to clone public repos, it does not have to include them. Plus they can be cached anyway, even on Windows, with credential helpers like the "Git Credential Manager for Windows" (https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows/releases/tag/v1.1.0). So having credentials in the `.gitmodules` is not a fatality.

Answer (score 20):

For some reason **submodule.module-name.active** didn't work for me.

That's why I used **submodule.module-name.ignore**

```
git config submodule.<your module path>.ignore all
```

https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules - here you can find description of possible values for parameter

Works for me for (new commits) and (modified content) messages.

Comment: But run `git add .` still commit the submodules.

Answer (score 8):

To add onto the accepted answer, I have found that adding the Git submodule folder to .gitignore actually causes issues - particularly when trying to create a fresh clone of the project. Specifically, running the normal submodule clone commands resulted in the submodule folder being empty:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update
git pull --recurse-submodules
```

Only by trying to re-run

```
git submodule add <Git repo> <submodule folder>
```

it was clear what the issue was, based on the output:

```
The following path is ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
<submodule folder>
Use -f if you really want to add it.
```

Instead of adding `-f`, I removed the Git submodule folder from .gitignore and re-ran the submodule clone commands - which now successfully created the folder. I think that there may be a bug in that one of the submodule clone commands respects .gitignore but does not warn that it is skipping a submodule accordingly.