# Git Submodules: Working only on one submodule of a repo

Tags: git, git-submodules

**Scenario:** In our MainProject, we have more than 12 SubProjects. Some team members works on all SubProjects, Some team members woks on 2-3 SubProjects and Some team members woks only on one SubProject.
**Git Repo Strucure:** We have created a main repository `MainProject.git`. And under it we have added different submodules for different projects, say `SP1, SP2,...,SP12`.

**Problem:** Now when any team member clones MainProject, empty directories of all SubProjects are cloned. **What we want** is, clone only specific submodules which are required for user and don't even want an empty folder.
How is it possible in `git`?

Answer (score 2):

> clone only specific submodules

This is possible. After cloning, try:

```
git submodule init
git submodule update <path to specific submodule>
```

> don't even want an empty folder

I don't think this is possible since the submodule folder is a part of superProject repo.

Try `git ls-files` to verify this.
And since we can only clone whole repository, empty folders will get created.

---

> what if someone deleted empty folder

There are two options:

- You can add all the submodule folders in `.gitignore` but that is not advisable (See [Do you ignore a git submodule in your .gitignore or commit it to your repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912022/do-you-ignore-a-git-submodule-in-your-gitignore-or-commit-it-to-your-repo)). The developer working on particular sub module would then have to remove the line before working on it. (Then the developers have to be careful not to push edited `.gitignore`, hence this doesn't solve the original problem of developers working carelessly)
- Or, you can use `pre-commit` `git hook` to restrict people from deleting folders

Comment: Thanks, but what if someone deleted empty folder! It gets removed from server too! what can I do to restrict it?

Comment: @Tejas: there are two options, you can add all the submodule folders in `.gitignore` but that is not advisable (See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912022/do-you-ignore-a-git-submodule-in-your-gitignore-or-commit-it-to-your-repo). You can also use `pre-commit` `git hook` to restrict people from deleting folders. 
If I were you I would have looked into using `.gitignore`

Comment: Thanks, very valuable suggestion, I recommend you to append this comment in your answer itself.