# not able to checkout origin branch after clone laradock folder in laravel project

Tags: laravel, git, docker, laradock

i not able checkout to other branch after i clone my laravel project..

now im using :

- Docker
- laravel project
- laradock inside my laravel project

so the shema folder will be like this

`Desktop/gushcloud/<laravel project>/laradoc`

when i want to checkout to origin branch or i run "git status". the error is this

`fatal: not a git repository: laradock/../.git/modules/laradock`

i already did run commend "git init".. the result is this

`Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Desktop/gushcloud/<laravel project>/.git/`

but i still now able to checkout origin branch. I go to my folder laradock and run "git init" and "git status".. the result is this

`fatal: not a git repository: /Desktop/gushcloud/<laravel project>/laradock/../.git/modules/laradock`

what should i do for this? please help me.

Comment: You should be .gitignoring your laradock folder, it is not something you want to be versioned by your package

Comment: i already set my .gitignore for my laradock folder

Comment: See if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912022/do-you-ignore-a-git-submodule-in-your-gitignore-or-commit-it-to-your-repo

Comment: Specifically: "Note that with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017), while not ignoring the gitlink, you can still ignore the submodule with: git config submodule.<name>.active false"

Comment: what a proper way to gitignore my laradock folder?'

Comment: Not an expert on this matter, but as that post says, gitignore does not apply to submodules, you need to ignore it in a different way.

Comment: @ferdinand can you try muti projects installation, https://laradock.io/getting-started/#B?