# How do I exclude local submodule version changes when bulk staging changes in git?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a repo with a submodule in it:

```
repo -
      |
      - repo_files
      - submodule1
```

When developing code for `repo`, I often do

```
git fetch && git rebase origin/main && git submodule update --recursive --remote
```

to have the latest code in my branch. When I do that, I see things like

```
Submodule path 'submodule1': checked out '2950846955e7f122b222492476698458b54b65ca'
```

when code for the submodule has been modified in its own repo. And I **do** want the submodule to be up to date locally, for code navigation reasons etc.

However, by project convention, we **do not** push submodule version changes in parent repos to avoid cluttering the changelog and the hassle of maintaining parent repos updated (those changes are fetched by CI automatically).

What I want is to be able to run bulk staging, i.e. `git add .`, without adding the submodule version changes to my commits.

I tried following advice from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7912101), but all it does is hiding submodule version changes from `git status`, while still adding those as a part of `git add .`. Adding `submodule1` to `.gitignore` doesn't help either.

Is there a way to achieve behaviour that I require?