# git submodules at HEAD rather than a SHA

Tags: git

We have a mega-repo that we want to break up. We want to have a bunch of "leaf" repos that all share some common central repos.  We own and control all the repos.  Git submodules seems like it might work.

The idea was to have each leaf repo submodule the common repo(s). It works, but whenever the central repo changes, we apparently need to make a commit to each of the leaf repos to update the hash of the submodule.

I really want to be able to pull the latest head as my submodule, and to not have to commit something for every update.  We'll CI test everything so we believe that is safe.  I want the changes propagated out ASAP, I just don't want every commit to a central repo to require another commit in each leaf repo.  That's just useless noise.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [force git submodule to always stay current](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443627/force-git-submodule-to-always-stay-current)

Comment: If you're using CI, could you swap from submodules to Composer-based build process? You can specify master/HEAD of your module repos in a `composer.json` dependencies file.