# Files stay modified in git repository

Tags: git

Today my Git did some crazy things the whole day, which I could not quite put my finger on. But now I got a very strange problem:

When I initialize a new repository in a directory, add all files (add -A) and commit them, some still stay modified:

[image: The Problem]

Nothing helps, not even a hard reset to HEAD. The diff is as followed:
[image: Diff]

I'm really at the end of my wit... The last thing I tried on this computer yesterday, was playing with some filters, when trying to [solve another problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IRAD.png).

But all I did there was modifying a config and .gitattributes locally in a completely different directory. So any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are not files, those are [git submodules](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) within your master repository.

Regarding the messages,

- `untracked content` means that there are some new files which are untracked in the submodule (if you didn't edit the submodule, consider these to be redundant files generated in code compilation, like *.so, *.pyc etc),
- while `modified content` means that newer commits were made to the repo, which you can update using `git submodule update`.

Check [Git: can I suppress listing of 'modified content'/dirty submodule entries in status, diff, etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3240881/1860929) to suppress these messages.

***EDIT***

The OP points out that he didn't add the submodules. In that case, these seem to be the effect of `gitlinks`; I think by adding these sub repositories, git created `gitlinks`, which are the same underlying mechanism that submodules use. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4161022/1860929) for more help.

Comment: I find that a little strange. I never used a submodule, but there are some other git-Repositories in this directory-tree. But there is no .gitmodules anywhere. Can you explain to me, what happens if you create a repository around a repository?

Comment: @Nils-o-mat Ah! I think by adding these sub repositories, you created `gitlinks`, which are the same underlying mechanism that submodules use. Check http://stackoverflow.com/q/4161022/1860929