# how i can use submodule gitlab in this stracture

Tags: git, github, gitlab, git-submodules

i work gitlab for my work . i use  multiply core (master) library for any project. during development each project maybe need add or change same feature in core library .

i use git submodule for sync new change to core (master) and commit it, it work perfectly . this is my question in core library after commit and push all change sync with master , how i can ignore same files or folder commit in submodule.

## my structure

core library

```
-library
--crm
---controller
----index.php
---model
----index.php
---view
----index.php
```

=================
this myproject

```
-library
--crm
---controller
----index.php
---model
----index.php
---view
----index.php (change)
----about.php (add)
```

==================

i build new repo for myproject , how i can ignore commit view folder in submodule  ? and model and controller allow commit and push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very simple can use

```
ignore = dirty
```

in .gitmodules

https://stackoverflow.com/a/5542452/4406856